# Mysql innerjoin clause doesn't working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables as follow:

**`talk` table**:

```
topic_id | topic_name | user_id (user who create topic)
  1           test1        1
  2           test2        2
```

**`talk_reply` table**:

```
talk_reply_id | message | topic_id | user_id (user who reply to specific topic)
     1            hi1        1         3
     2            hi2        1         4
```

**`user` table**:

```
user_id  | name
  1        mark
  2        pedro
  3        gates
  4        steve
```

My query are as follow:

```
SELECT `tr`.`message`, 
       `tr`.`user_id`, 
       `tr`.`topic_id`,  
       `u`.`name` 
FROM `talk_reply` AS `tr`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `u` ON tr.user_id = u.user_id WHERE (tr.topic_id=1)
```

But I only get 1 result instead of 2, what am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to get?

Comment: i want to get name of user who reply to specific topic from talk_reply table, in this case topic_id 1

Comment: @zlippr - the statement you give with the data you've presented returns two rows. There's either an error in the data you are *actually* using, you are not showing us the *actual* statement or MySQL's sql engine contains a serious bug. I doubt it's the latter :)

Comment: is this what you mean? [SQLFiddle Demo(click here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4988b/2) *your query is working*

Comment: @zlippr actually i did not modify your query, i just paste it on sqlfiddle and run it.

Comment: @JohnWoo so it must be something wrong the way i wrote here.Thanks to notify me!

Comment: @zlippr - You are not reading the comments John Woo posts. **Your statement was fine to begin with**

Comment: @JohnWoo hi, the problems is not the query but with the user id which not exists in users table, thats the reason why i only get 1 user data.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.topic_id, t.user_id, u.name, tr.message
FROM talk t
INNER JOIN talk_reply tr ON tr.topic_id = t.topic_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE t.topic_id = '1'
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT tr.topic_id, tr.user_id, u.name, tr.message
FROM talk_reply tr
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = tr.user_id
WHERE tr.topic_id = '1'
```

Comment: OP's select list columns are different and he needs only columns from talk_reply and users table.And his query is fine it should work.No need to use talk table here

Comment: I agree with @AnandPhadke here +1

Comment: @AnandPhadke: Ic, I didn't noticed that table `talk` doesn't need here. I've updated the code above. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tr.`message`, 
       tr.`user_id`, 
       tr.`topic_id`,  
       (select u.`name` from users u where u.user_id = tr.user_id) name
FROM `talk_reply` as tr
WHERE tr.topic_id=1
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4988b/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.topic_id, a.user_id,b.message,c.name 
from talk a 
inner join talk_reply.b on a.topic_id=b.topic.id
inner join users c on c.user_id=a.user_id 
where t.topic_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT `tr`.`message`, 
       `tr`.`user_id`, 
       `tr`.`topic_id`,  
       `u`.`name` 
FROM `talk_reply` AS `tr`
AND `users` AS `u` 
WHERE tr.user_id = u.user_id AND (tr.topic_id=1)
```

Comment: not working #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `users` AS `u` WHERE tr.user_id = u.user_id AND tr.topic_id=1 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6